# Besides cgroups, are there other lightweight os resource isolation schemes?

Tags: cgroups, resource-isolation

I would like to know if there are other operating system resource isolation schemes besides cgroups to isolate and control resources such as cpu and memory...

Answer (score 0):

For the CPU, under Linux, one can also use the `isolcpus` [command line parameter](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) of the kernel:

> isolcpus=
> [KNL,SMP,ISOL] Isolate a given set of CPUs from disturbance.
> [Deprecated - use cpusets instead]

But as pointed out by the documentation, it is deprecated: cpusets subsystem of the cgroups are preferred now. To achieve an optimal isolation with the latter, the [partrt](https://github.com/OpenEneaLinux/rt-tools) tool is available.